# list-view & navbar font color change jquerymobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

How to change font color of: "Page 1", "Page 2", Page 3", "Link A", "Link B", "Link C" in list-view and navbar using jQueryMobile 1.4.4?

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
  <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>      
  <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>           
</ul>
    <br/><br />
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link A</a></li>      
        <li><a href="#">Link B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link C</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image: navigation]

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
<style type="text/css">
li:a {
    color:red;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it should be `li a {color:red;}`

Comment: No, it does not work

Comment: try with this `li a {color:red !important;}`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/53gpyr5f/

Answer (score 0):

```
ul#autocomplete li a {
    color: #526c5a;
}
```